# Custom labels using geom_bin2d with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a 2d plot where the boxes/tiles are labelled according to a column for the input data frame. I've used geom_bin2d (and stat_bin2d) to do similar things before but it seems to only allow count or density to be the actual plotted material. Example code is this:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2010, 4), rep(2011, 4), rep(2012, 4)), Rank = rep(1:4, 3), 
                 Diff = c(rep(0, 3), 1, 0, -1, 2, 0, -3, rep(0, 3)))


ggplot(df, aes(Year, Rank, Diff)) +
  geom_bin2d() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='gray', high='red')
```

What I want is something like this but with the guide bar also corresponding to the data displayed in the boxes. Note I added these numbers by hand for illustration purposes. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to bin here, as (if I understand your question) you're trying to plot the values of one variable at lattice points represented by two other variables.

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(Year), factor(Rank), fill=Diff)) +
  geom_tile(height=0.8, width=0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Diff)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low='gray', high='red') +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(x="Year", y="Rank") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This does indeed solve it! Using `fill` here seems to be the missing link.